# Is this possible to change the way of Eclipse formatting the code?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting

Usually the eclipse auto formatting work like this:

[image]

But I really prefer the variable format like this:

[image]

Comment: Not sure but try Window -> Preferences - Java -> Code Style -> Formatter. Create a custom formatter.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "Window/Preferences/Java/Code Style/Formatter". There you can configure almost everything. Detailed tutorial for the same can be found [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/codestyle/ref-preferences-formatter.htm)